# preg replace to generate a link

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm developping a simple cms and in some cases I want to store a paragraph in the database which may contain some links but I don't want to store html code in the database, I want it to be as follows:

some text, some text ||keyword||http://an-external-site.com/keyword|| some text and some text

and then use php to generate a link like this:

some text, some text <a href="http://an-external-site.com/keyword">keyword</a> some text and some text

So, how to do it? with preg_replace() for example

And is there a way to have the url point to an internal page within my site using a pre-defined variable, for example

some text, some text ||keyword||MS/keyword|| some text and some text

which will be:

some text, some text <a href="http://mysite.com/keyword">keyword</a> some text and some text

where MS refers to my site for example http://mysite.com/

So here the php function gets the pattern and then decides whether to simply use the full url as in the example 1 or to replace MS with the pre-defined variable which equals http://mysite.com/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use some class like [bbcode](http://freecode.com/projects/bbcode) to directly get non-html code in your project.

If you still want to use regexp you can use something like this:

```
$pattern = '=^(.*)<a(.*)href\="?(\S+)"([^>]*)>(.*)</a>(.*)$=msi';
while (preg_match($pattern, $row, $txt))
{
  /* $txt[3] holds the link. */
  echo $txt[3]."\n";

  $row = $txt[1]." here was a link ".$txt[6];
}

/* print $row */
print "<br>".nl2br($row);
```

Comment: thanks for the idea but how should it work as you didn't mention the pattern used in the paragraph where the function should find anything like ||...||...||